# Finding specific part of text in a field which starts with a specific character in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to write an inner join where Table_1's identifier is an unique field and Table_2's field which is being used for the join has the identifier value embedded in a text and that text starts with **"DJ_"**. Here, from Table_2 I want to extract the identifier value from those tuples which start only with **"DJ_"**, not any other text.

For example, the Table_1's identifier value for the join is 12345. The same identifier is a part of a text field in Table_2; the text looks like **"DJ_12_XYZ_1_YTR_12345.trt"**. So, I want the text before and after "12345" to be removed while joining it as Table_2's identifier.

Comment: Which version of sql server? Having access to string_split affects the answer.

If you're the designer, joining on bits of strings is terrible for performance, and should be normalised if possible.

Comment: The version is 2014. And, this cannot be normalized as this is the only field that can join the tables.

Comment: Have a look at [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). For a more detailed answer [edit] your question and include the tables' `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text form. Also add the query you're having so far.

Comment: If you're using 2014, why have you tagged 2008 and 2012..?

Comment: In table 2 is the format of the identifier consistent?

Comment: FYI: Thats going to perform badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to join using like, and some sample data.
I had to escape the underscore, since that's already a special character for like.

The idea is to match strings starting with '_' and ending with '_' or '.'

I didn't filter prefix, it's a trivial AND LIKE at the end.

```
CREATE TABLE t1(id int identity, val varchar(50))

CREATE TABLE t2(id int identity, t1_id varchar(50))

INSERT INTO t1(val)
VALUES('1'),('2'),('3')

INSERT INTO t2(t1_id)
VALUES('a_1_x'),('b_2.'),('c_d'),('c_3.abc')

SELECT 
t1.id,
t2.t1_id

FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
    ON t2.t1_id LIKE '%[_]' + CAST(t1.id AS varchar(50)) + '[.|_]%'
```

https://rextester.com/ZGJIG68078

Comment: You could change the `like` pattern to include the `'DJ_'` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You have an easy problem and a harder problem.

To get the records you want to join that start with DJ_...

a simple `where LEFT(string,3) = 'DJ_'`

Now getting the number out.

This one is fun...

```
substring(right('DJ_12_XYZ_1_YTR_12345.trt',charindex('_',reverse('DJ_12_XYZ_1_YTR_12345.trt'),1)),2,5)
```